# Angular scope variable not updating after save

Tags: angularjs

I have a save function in which the changes are saving and after the success response of save I am calling a get function which fetches latest updated data from DB. But the changes are not reflecting in the view.

What is the solution for this?
code is like this

```
 $scope.saveMenu = function () {
        $('.save-button').prop('disabled', true);
        $http({
            url: '/api/menu/save',
            method: 'POST',
            data: 'aff=' +JSON.stringify($scope.aff) + '&menuAccess='+ JSON.stringify($scope.menuAccess) + '&brokerId=' + $scope.filter.business_filter,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            var oResponse = angular.fromJson(response);
            $('.save-button').prop('disabled', false);
            if (oResponse.success) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.getUsers();
                });

                $('.save').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.save').fadeOut();
                }, 2000);

            } else {
                $window.location.href = $rootScope.ng_url + '/error/' + oResponse.status_code;
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.getUsers = function () {
        $scope.filter.view_group_filter = ($scope.filter.view_group_filter != '') ? $scope.filter.view_group_filter : 0;

        if ($scope.filter.business_filter != -5) {
            $('#group').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#group').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        $http.get('/api/menu/users/' + $scope.filter.business_filter + '/' + $scope.filter.view_group_filter)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    // success callback
                    var oResponse = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                    if (oResponse.success) {
                        $scope.aff = oResponse.data.Aff;
                    } else {
                        $window.location.href = $rootScope.ng_url + '/error/' + oResponse.status_code;
                    }
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: It will be complicated to answer without a piece of code

Comment: Code sample added

Comment: A thing: you need to call jquery events in a $timeout()... not is the same thing of your setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

$apply brings you into angular context.
No need to use $scope.$apply as you are using $http, you are already in angular context.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.getUsers();
});
```

Change this to,

```
$scope.getUsers();
```

Here, setTimeout not updating any scope variable, no harm. But if it is updating any scope data. Instead of using setTimeout use $timeout which internally calls $apply and hence $digest.